# Python: Dynamically Updating Image Viewer

Tags: python, image

I'm building a small program that essentially outputs 'video' from a webcam using Pygame.  Is there any way to easily view an image, but every half-second or so, update the image to the latest version? Most methods to load an image require an external viewer and only load the image into memory once, thus forcing the programmer into closing the viewer and reopening it every time the image updates.  As I said, is there any small module that creates a basic image viewer and can be controlled easily?